# Create a web Ajax version of excel?

Tags: ajax, spreadsheet

I'm trying to figure out how to create basic functionality of a excel spreadsheet in a web app. Is basic Ajax the best way or is there a good framework for this?

Answer (score 1):

[qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/) is one of the best for these kind of applications, in my opinion.

The reason is because it implements its own Widget system (like [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/)), completely using divs and canvas elements, making the development experience much more like a *desktop*.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to implement saving? Or semi-advanced data retrieval (such as from a database)?

Because I think you can get away with just the Javascript and not have to tap the server too much.

Comment: Yes there will be a database backend part